# Should a mutator return a bool or is it an unnecessary sanity check?

Tags: java, oop, coding-style, setter

In other words when you write a mutator for a class such as the example I have given below should it return a bool so the main program can confirm that the instance variable was updated or is this an unnecessary sanity check? Is there any standard that suggests this is what you should do or does such said standard suggest that you should use a void mutator so nothing is returned to the main program? Or is this "issue" just dependent on the programmer?

For example, should I use a mutator like this?

```
public boolean changeString (String newValue) {
  if (newValue != NULL) { 
    someString = newValue; 
    return true;
  } 
  else {
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Or should I use a mutator like this?

```
public void changeString (String newValue) {
  if (newValue != NULL) { 
    someString = newValue; 
  }
}
```

Comment: He is probably asking if it is recommended to have a setter return a boolean to indicate if the value has actually changed.

Comment: Indeed that is what I am asking sorry for the limited example and what appears to be a poorly asked question...

Comment: Hopefully that is better? @JohnKugelman

Comment: Yes, much better, thanks. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Anyway, while the question is better now, it's still mostly a matter of opinion. It depends on the design of your API/application, really.

Comment: If the value provided isn't valid you should certainly throw an exception that says so, not just weakly return 'false' and allowed the caller to ignore it. Some mutators return false if he value didn't change, but in practice this is usually ignored as you usually don't care.

Comment: Cay Horstmann recommends that a mutator returns void.